# Create generic extension to make a deep copy of a List with Data Class

Tags: list, kotlin, generics, data-class, generic-function

Hi I'm trying to create a generic function to make a deep copy of list using the copy() method that a Data class provide us.

I'm using the method that I found on other post which returns a list of objects being deep copied:

`listDataClass.map{ it.copy() }`

But I can't seem to know how to make it as a generic function for data class so I'm really curious to see how'd you make one like this.

Comment: This can’t be done with generics because data classes don’t share a superclass with a `copy` method. You would have to use reflection, and it wouldn’t be able to identify at compile time whether your list contains data class instances or not.

Comment: Oh that's sad but makes sense, thank you for your answer! You can post it and I'll give you the correct answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using kotlin reflection magic, you can do it like this:

```kotlin
class NotADataClassException(clazz: KClass<out Any>): Exception("$clazz is not a data class")

fun List<T>.deepCopy(): List<T> {
    return map { item ->
        if (!item::class.isData) {
            throw NotADataClassException(item::class)
        } else {
            item::class.members.first { it.name == "copy" }.callBy(emptyMap()) as T
        } 
    }
}
```

However, this is bad because of the following reasons:

- This doesn't constrain the elements to data classes at compile time (that is what we wanted to do with the generics!) instead, it throws an exception.
- Kotlin reflection is *slow* and *big*, and reflection is used for every item.

Comment: You could use `fun <T> List<T>.deepCopy(): List<T>` with `as T` instead of `as Any` so the copied list still has the same type as the original.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04, I have edited my answer.